# Issue with latest Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

In my latest WP7 project I added using Nuget a reference to the Silverlight Toolkit for WP7.
In one of my pages I added a new namespace reference at the top as I've done on previous occasions:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

However, when I try to add a toolkit control to the page, I get only one option after typing

```
<toolkit:HeaderedItemsControl
```

All the other toolkit controls are not accessible from XAML.
Did anyone face any similar issues with the lastest Nuget release for Silverlight Toolkit on WP7?
Am I missing something (I've used the toolkit before without any issues... although I agree I didn't use Nuget on that occasion)?
I can access the other toolkit classes from code without any problems...

Any help or suggestions are welcomed!

Thank you in advance!
Andrei

Comment: ok.... error between chair and monitor! the reference is wrong: by mistake I was referencing System.Windows.Controls instead of Microsoft.Phone.Controls